# How to calculate period between a specific date?

Tags: flutter

I'm studying Flutter and in my application I need to calculate how many days are left until the 17th of the next month. There is no way to have a specific date, so it would be crucial to have today's date and add 1 month and calculate how many days are left.

For example: Today is 2021-09-09 and there are 38 days to 2021-10-17. The function does not calculate the 17th of the current month, but the following month.

Any idea how to make a function that takes the current date, adds 1 month and calculates how many days are left until the 17th? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically copy the `DateTime` object with 1 added to the current month number and the day set to the 17th.  Then subtract the two `DateTime` objects and convert the resulting `Duration` to days.  It's important to perform all calculations in UTC so that Daylight Saving Time adjustments aren't a factor.

```dart
/// Returns the number of days to the specified [day] in the month following
/// [startDate].
int daysToNextMonthDay(DateTime startDate, int day) {
  // Recreate `startDate` as a UTC `DateTime`.  We don't care about the
  // time.
  //
  // Note that this isn't the same as `startDate.toUtc()`.  We want a UTC
  // `DateTime` with specific values, not necessarily the UTC time
  // corresponding to same moment as `startDate`.
  startDate = DateTime.utc(startDate.year, startDate.month, startDate.day);
  var nextMonthDay = DateTime.utc(startDate.year, startDate.month + 1, day);

  // Verify that the requested day exists in the month.
  if (nextMonthDay.day != day) {
    throw ArgumentError(
      'Day $day does not exist for the month following ${startDate.month}',
    );
  }

  return nextMonthDay.difference(startDate).inDays;
}

void main() {
  var now = DateTime(2021, 9, 9);
  print(daysToNextMonthDay(now, 17)); // Prints: 38
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
void main() {
  DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  print(daysLeft(date.subtract(Duration(days: 1))));
}

bool isLeapYear(int year) {
  if (year % 4 == 0) {
    if (year % 100 == 0) {
      if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
  
int daysLeft(DateTime date){
  int daysLeft = 0;
  switch(date.month){
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
    case 12: daysLeft = 31 - date.day + 17; break;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11: daysLeft = 30 - date.day + 17; break;
    case 2: if(isLeapYear(date.year)){
      daysLeft = 29 - date.day + 17;
      break;
    }else{
      daysLeft = 28 - date.day + 17;
    }
  }
  return daysLeft;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the help. I'm a beginner, I'm sorry, but how can I make this a function? in my app I have a Text Widget that says "It's %days% left for the next post". Is there a way to include this? Thanks.

Comment: Text("It's "+daysLeft(YOURDATEVARIABLE).toString()+" left for the next post")

Comment: The function returns 8 days, it's not taking the 17th of the next month :/

Comment: it works fine I guess. can you tell the correct output for today's date i.e. 10th Sep 2021.

Comment: do you want to calculate the days every time till next month 17th or just next 17th

Comment: updated the solution to count days till next month 17th every time.

Comment: @JesséLopesPereira can you verify this.